# Aggregating to hourly data

Tags: sql, aggregate, average, hour, minute

I have one time column structured like this

- 02/01/2003  07:01:42
- 02/01/2003  07:04:02
- 02/01/2003  07:36:11
- 02/01/2003  07:53:09

and an adjacent column with values as integers

- 2
- 4
- 1
- 1

I want to get the aggregate of the values (average) in hourly intervals. So:

- 02/01/2003  07

with "2" adjacent to hour 7 (2 is the average of 2,4,1,1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test_data (
    test_date  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    test_value INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_data VALUES
  ('2003-02-01 07:01:42', 2),
  ('2003-02-01 07:04:02', 4),
  ('2003-02-01 07:36:11', 1),
  ('2003-02-01 07:53:09', 1),
  ('2003-02-01 08:02:16', 5);
```

```
SELECT extract(YEAR FROM test_date)  t_year,
       extract(MONTH FROM test_date) t_month,
       extract(DAY FROM test_date)   t_day,
       extract(HOUR FROM test_date)  t_hour,
       avg(test_value)               t_avg
  FROM test_data
GROUP BY extract(YEAR FROM test_date),
         extract(MONTH FROM test_date),
         extract(DAY FROM test_date),
         extract(HOUR FROM test_date);
```

will result in

| t_year | t_month | t_day | t_hour | t_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2003 | 2 | 1 | 7 | 2.0000 |
| 2003 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 5.0000 |